# How to use inputs for key value hash attributes in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jsonb, actionview

I have Schedule model with `jsonb(hash)` fields.

```
create_table :schedules do |t|
  t.jsonb :monday
  t.jsonb :tuesday
  t.jsonb :wednesday

  t.timestamps null: false
 end

schedule = Schedule.create(monday: {start: '8:00', end: '21:30'})
```

So I trying to show this `start, end` attributes as an input for show/edit form.
I know this solution is wrong `(undefined method`input' for start, end)`. How could I show this inputs for jsonb hash? Or maybe there are better solutions?

```
<%= form_for @excursion do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :schedule do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.fields_for :monday do |fff| %>
          <%= fff.input :start %>
          <%= fff.input :end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit 'save' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the input fields that they are nested hash/json, and also on the controller, first on the view:

```
<%= form.input "monday[start]" %>
<%= form.input "monday[end]" %>
```

And on the controller:

```
def schedule_params
  params.require(:schedule).permit(:monday => [:start, :end])
end
```

Then you should be good to go

Comment: undefined method `monday[start]' for #<Schedule:0x000000097a0630>